# How to solve: "Cask 'caskroom' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists."

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I try to run `brew doctor` I get the error message below with no other details.

```
  brew doctor
  Error: Cask 'caskroom' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
```

However I am able to run `brew list` and do not see any pkg named "caskroom". I also was able to run "update" and "upgrade" and they seemed to complete successfully.

Is there a "verbose" mode which would give me more information about where this error is occurring or is there a way I can manually remove this reference to "Cask 'caskroom'?